# Movie about a white father being killed by a black man causing them to become skinheads?

Tags: identify-this-movie

Could someone please help me recall a movie bout a white father being killed by a black man causing children to become skinheads who get raped in prison showers and killed by a black man.

I watched it about 15-20 years ago when I was 19, it was pretty recent movie at the time, it was in black and white and I believe it was set in America.

Plot:

- A father of two children (both males) was murdered by a black man
  (not by accident) due to some gang issues.
- This causes the older brother to become extremely racist and make his own skinhead gang.
- I believe in a scene he has a basketball game against a famous gang around the area.
- He leads an attack on a grocery stored owned by a black man with many black employers
- Eventually the big brother gets a hefty prison sentence
- This is because I remember one of the scenes very vividly, the brother chases and shoots a black man and chases this other black man down the street to stamp his head in.
- While the older brother is in prison the younger brother gets influenced by the other neo-nazi gangs in the area and he joins one.
- I think the younger brothers teacher is worried about him and tells his older brother who has now served about 5 years I think.
- The older brother becomes more educated in prison and decides to change his mind
- I believe because he is in the prison with other skinhead gang members, he decides to change his outlook on black people and seeing this as an act of betrayal the skinhead members assault and rape the older brother in prison
- I believe he is released on parole but by this time when he sees his younger brother, he is shocked because the younger brother is all skinheady...
- With all these gang tattoos and things I believe in the last scene a young black male kills the younger brother and the older brother is mortified by the life they lived

I believe one of the brothers had a Nazi swasticka on his chest

Comment: Jeez man, if you know all that, any simple google search would have given you the title eh.

Comment: iam sorry i just dont know how to work google well and my cousin told me to ask you guys

Comment: Google search is very simple to use just type in a few key words and hit enter, as I already said "Nazi tattoo on chest movie" would have worked

Answer (score 33):

I just saw that last description and I immediatly thought [American History X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_History_X)

If you type in on Google "Nazi tattoo on chest movie" your first result should be [American History X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_History_X) ;-)

I think the scene you're thinking about with the curb stomping incident is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya10UH1UdTk).

According to Wikipedia:

Their father was killed by black drug dealers

> Danny and Derek's father Dennis Vinyard was murdered by black drug dealers after being sent on a call to fight a fire in a drug den.

The racism begins when

> In a television interview conducted after Dennis's death, Derek erupts in a long racist tirade. Shortly thereafter, Cameron Alexander and Derek form a white supremacist gang called the Disciples of Christ.

The basketball game vs famous gang scene

> Derek is reluctantly dragged into a 3-on-3 game against several members of the Crips in which the prize is control of the recreation center basketball courts. After winning with his friends.

Attack on supermarket **not grocery store.**

> Derek leads a large gang of skinheads to attack a supermarket owned by a Korean that included African-American and Latino workers

The sodomizing scene

> Derek joins the Aryan Brotherhood, but after about a year, he becomes disillusioned because some members have ties to other prison gangs who are of different ethnicities. As punishment, he is beaten and sodomized in the shower by the Aryan Brotherhood members

The scene where the younger brother dies

> Danny is ambushed and killed in the bathroom by a young black student named Little Henry. Derek arrives at the school and mourns for Danny.

Comment: This has to be it!!. You were fast!.:)

Comment: Ikr thanks I just saw the description of the Nazi Swastika on his chest and it just clicked lol, I'll make my answer more detailed hold up

Comment: To my (Canadian English) ear, "supermarket" and "grocery store" are equivalent.

Comment: first movie that came to mind too

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain In the Netherlands we only have a supermarket and that 100% fits the description Americans give to grocery store :)

Comment: In the UK grocery store = small local store that sells fruit and veg whereas supermarket sells all sorts of things